# Como extrair dados de um url XML para labels do Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net

[![Detalhamento da questão][1]][1]

Estou querendo fazer um botão de pesquisa pelo código do ISBN usando o Virtual Studio 2013, no qual ele me retornaria dados do site ISBNDB.com em formato XML, que seriam inseridos diretamente nos `labels` correspondentes, porém não consigo estou conseguindo. Como posso proceder?

**[ATUALIZAÇÃO]**

Eu consegui obter os dados da XML da seguinte forma;
1º instalei para a manipulação de dados foi instalado o pacote NuGet "CHilkatDotNet4", a seguir, o código para obtenção dos dados:

```
Private Sub ISBN_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ISBN_btn.Click
    Dim xml0 As New Chilkat.Xml()

    '  The Chilkat XML component/class is freeware.'

    Dim xml As Chilkat.Xml
    xml = xml0.HttpGet("http://isbndb.com/api/books.xml?access_key=SUA_CHAVE_DE_ACESSO=isbn&value1=" + ISBN10_txtbox.Text)
    If (xml Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox("Livro não encontrado")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '  First, navigate to the BookData node:'
    xml.FirstChild2()
    xml.FirstChild2()        

    '  Show the Title and AuthorsText: '
    ISBN13_txtbox.Text = ISBN13_txtbox.Text & xml.GetAttrValue("isbn13") & vbCrLf
    ISBN13_txtbox.Refresh()
    Titulo_txtbox.Text = Titulo_txtbox.Text & xml.GetChildContent("Title") & vbCrLf
    Titulo_txtbox.Refresh()
    TituloLong_txtbox.Text = TituloLong_txtbox.Text & xml.GetChildContent("TitleLong") & vbCrLf
    TituloLong_txtbox.Refresh()
    Autor_txtbox.Text = Autor_txtbox.Text & xml.GetChildContent("AuthorsText") & vbCrLf
    Autor_txtbox.Refresh()

    '  Show the publisher_id attribute of the PublisherText node:'
    Dim xml2 As Chilkat.Xml

    xml2 = xml.FindChild("PublisherText")
    Editora_txtbox.Text = Editora_txtbox.Text & xml2.GetAttrValue("publisher_id")



    '  Save the XML to a file:'
    xml.SaveXml("book.xml")
End Sub
```

Com isso ele me trás os dados da busca feita pelo ISBN e os joga direto aos text box exatamente como queria, se caso não o encontrar, uma msg aparece dizendo "Livro Não Encontrado".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ainda está com alguns erros, por exemplo, se algum campo for preenchido manualmente e depois colocar para ser feito a busca, ele apresenta um erro. Porém ainda estou a analisar.

Bom minha duvida agora é, como fazer para pegar que aparecem neste link https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn+8525034304 ? Antes de mais nada, tentei usar o código acima mas acho que só funciona em XML e pelo visto, este do link é outro formato, então como proceder..?

Comment: Usuário postou uma dúvida, depois de resolver editou a questão para colocar outra pergunta.

Comment: Bom dia @jbueno não vejo problema, desde que ainda não tenha recebido respostas ainda. O que ele precisa é organizar a pergunta, esta horrível de ler :)

Comment: Bom dia @GuilhermeNascimento, mas a pergunta tem duas respostas que abordam somente o primeiro problema...

Comment: @jbueno Vixe eu não tinha visto que haviam respostas, desculpe, realmente não parece estar correto, talvez um rollback apenas para o primeiro problema e orientar o AP  a explicar o problema melhor e/ou fazer uma nova pergunta :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Acho que é mesmo uma boa ideia (:

Comment: Esse outro formato no link googleapis é **[tag:json]**, @Everton

Comment: @jbueno, pois é, precisa de um pouco de curadoria  aqui, o troço parece bem bagunçado... não tenho certeza se os votos para fechar são corretos... confira: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1682/o-que-fazer-quando-o-o-p-muda-sua-pergunta/1684#1684

Comment: Não tinha me deparado com uma situação dessas antes, então não sabia ao certo o que fazer. Obrigado @brasofilo

Comment: @jbueno, camaleões e vampiros não são simplesmente criaturas míticas do Meta :)

Comment: Olá, desculpa ai galera, não sabia q poderia alterar a pergunta assim do nada...
Na verdade eu queria ter deixado a questão original como estava, porém ainda não me é permitido colocar mais de 2 links :(

Comment: @brasofilo obrigado.
Nesse caso eu deveria colocar uma nova pergunta dizendo como extrair os dados json para uma form aplication....certo?

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria que você desse um exemplo de como está tentando fazer e não apenas dissesse "**não estou conseguindo.**"

Mas vamos lá, o caminho das pedras é esse:

Importe o namespace `System.Xml.Linq` - Trabalhar com Linq é muito mais simples nesse caso

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

var doc = XDocument.Load("caminhoDoArquivo.xml");
var titulo = doc.Descendants("Title").First().Value; //Pega o valor do primeiro elemento "Title"
```

Note que o exemplo acima irá pegar os valores do primeiro "elemento filho" de **BookList** e, aparentemente, esse nó pode ter vários elementos **BookData**.

Você pode pegar o valor de todos esses elementos iterando o nó **BookList**

```
var bookList = doc.Descendants("BookList");

foreach(var bookData in bookList)
{
    var titulo = bookData.Descendants("Title").First().Value;
    // Aqui será necessário jogar os valores numa lista ou algo semelhante
}
```

Comment: Bom, desculpe a forma como coloquei a pergunta, na verdade não sabia bem por onde começar, já havia tentado alguns métodos antes, porém esqueci de colocar aqui..

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar obter o que está entre duas tags com esse método:

```
Public Shared Function GetBetween(IStringStr As String, IBefore As String, IPast As String)
   On Error Resume Next
   Dim iString As String
   iString = IStringStr
   iString = Right(iString, Len(iString) - InStr(iString, IBefore) - Len(IBefore) + 1)
   iString = Mid(iString, 1, InStr(iString, IPast) - 1)
   GetBetween = iString
End Function
```

Para usar, use esse código; como um exemplo:

```
LabelTitulo.Text = GetBetweem(ArquivoXML.ToString(), "<Title>", "</Title>")
```